# Upload a file into server without click on submit button

Tags: php, upload, download, speed-test

I want to first download a file from server and then as soon as the download gets complete i want to upload the same file back into the server and both of this action must be performed one after the other with just a single button click at the beginning.

Im actually trying to write codes for speedtest so bascially when i click on a link saying START TEST it should first download a file into the system and then without any further User interaction it should upload the same file back again.
Can someone help me out with it.

Comment: Do you have code, and what have you tried if you do? And if not, then Google "ajax upload php"

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results

Comment: no i am familiar with the basic way of uploading a file into the server but i am confused on how to upload the file without using a form i.e. when we upload using form we get $_FILES[formname][tmp_file] but when we dont have a form how are we suppose to get the tmp_file to upload into the server

Comment: As stated in my initial comment, Google "ajax upload php" and you will find many results. @user2869895

Comment: Hey Fred it was good but i was rather looking up for something in which the user is not asked to select a file it rather selects the file that was initially downloaded.

Comment: @user2869895 You mean the file is sent/uploaded "TO" the user as a pre-defined file as a box pops up to prompt the user to "save to" on their computer?

Comment: No u didnt get my question i guess. First when i click the button a file gets downloaded and as soon as the download gets completed the same file should get uploaded in the server. So basically what happens is that user will never know the file even got uploaded.

Comment: @user2869895 Ok, well I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of file uploading with cURL you could start with:

```
$ch = curl_init('http://api.blabla.com/huhu.php');
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array(
        'files[]' => '@/path/to/file',
    ),
));
if (false === ($res = curl_exec($ch))) {
    die("Upload failed: " . curl_error($ch));
}
```

The string '@/path/to/file' has a special meaning because it starts with an @; the string that directly follows it should contain the path of a file you wish to upload.

Comment: we are asking the user to select a file in here but what i actually want is that the form should take in a file from a predefined location so that the user will not even realize that the file started uploading.

Comment: and how about where it will be uploaded.? i mean the destination folder